# Render Control Without Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently working with an internal framework. It's all great, but the framework doesn't use aspx pages, it renders pages using Response.Write. The issue I am having is that I need to use a rad control on the page, so all I need to do is generate the rad control to get the HTML code so I can dump it onto the page. Is this possible? I've tried creating a Page object to get it working, but it doesn't work. It seems that when a page is called, it's doing some other initializing. I also tried casting the HttpContext.Current.Handler to a page, but that didn't work because they are using another class, not System.Web.UI.Page to handle requests.

At this point I'm not too sure what else to try. If I can mimc the Page creation class, that would be wonderful. Does anyone know the exact steps to create and initialize a Page object properly?

Hopefully this makes sense... if not, I'll try to make it more understandable.

Thanks!

### Update

Just wanted to give you the code that I am playing with. Hopefully this will show you what I am trying to do:

this is working:

```
HtmlForm f = new HtmlForm();
            RadEditor re = new RadEditor();
            f.ID = "form1";


            this.Page.Controls.Add(f);

            re.ID = "rdControl";

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

            //Page p = new Page();//(Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;

            //HtmlForm f = new HtmlForm();

            //p.Controls.Add(f);

            f.Controls.Add(re);
```

This is not working:

```
HtmlForm f = new HtmlForm();
            RadEditor re = new RadEditor();
            f.ID = "form1";
Page p = new Page();

            p.Controls.Add(f);

            re.ID = "rdControl";

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

            //Page p = new Page();//(Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;

            //HtmlForm f = new HtmlForm();

            //p.Controls.Add(f);

            f.Controls.Add(re);
```

ideally I'd like to get the second one working to some degree so I can generate the code. Sorry about the mess. It was my test code.

### Update

So I thought about it, and I think I know where the issue is. The control is trying to access a bunch of files that are not included within the dll, like language files, styles, js files, etc. I think the issue might be that when I create a new instance of Page, it doesn't know where that page is in reference to all the resources. Is there a way i can set the page to a "virtual" URL? Right now I am playing with this code:

```
HttpContext context = new HttpContext(new HttpRequest(string.Empty, "http://localhost:2090/default.aspx", string.Empty), new HttpResponse(null));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of research, I managed to find out what I was missing to generate the page. Apparently there is a function, p.DesignerInitialize(), that initializes the page. Once this is called, it generates the page, and controls can be rendered off of it. Here is my new function that I am using:

```
public string RenderRad()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

        MyPage p = new MyPage();
        p.DesignerInitialize();

        HtmlForm f = new HtmlForm();

        p.Controls.Add(f);

        f.Controls.Add(re);

        re.RenderControl(hw);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

I also have a class that inherits from Page that will disable the check for all controls to be in the form:

```
 public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of this method you developed? I'm really curious as I'm pulling my hair out getting telerik controls to work 'my' way inside custom server controls. Its pretty sad they don't support it better.

Comment: I'm guessing this doesn't work with user controls because they need to be compiled and this code doesn't do that.

Answer (score 5):

You can try the RenderControl method, which writes to an HtmlTextWriter

```
var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
myControl.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
var s = stringWriter.ToString();
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I think it would work with normal controls, but the Rad Control is using something else that's not getting initialized in the page.

Comment: It's one of those custom controls, http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx

Comment: Ok. You should try asking your question on the support forum.

Comment: I tried, no body knows. Hopefully someone here might give me an idea.