# RenderControl in HtmlTextWriter - InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to render a Control object which is just created on the fly when the user send a postback request. To do so, I use the code below:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
HtmlTextWriter ht = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb));
Rating r = new Rating("r", 5, 3, No, Big);
r.RenderControl(ht);
```

which unfortunately yields to an `InvalidOperationException` at the last line and with the following error:

> The page can not be null. Make sure that this operation is performed in the context of an ASP.NET request.

I probably misunderstood the way I should use this `RenderControl` method, and I hope you can help me with my problem.

Thank you,
David

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're attaching your new Rating control to your Page control before attempting to render it.

From the MSDN [docs for RenderControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htwek607.aspx), the internals of the call are going to be looking for the enclosing Page, and performing some activities based on the Page object's settings.

You might add a placeholder in your page and insert the Rating control there before attempting to render it.

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to get html code from a `System.Web.UI.Control` object without a http request?

Comment: @Davd33 - you might check out [this thread here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346435/render-control-without-page) - the OP found a way to call RenderControl in a similar scenario by creating a custom Page class and creating an instance of it, in code, to contain the custom control.