# Conversion of Html to pdf using itextsharp in C# and asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, pdf, itext

**html code::**

```
 <div id="divprint" runat="server">

 <table>
   <tr align="left">
          <td colspan="4" align="left">
              Employee Name :
          <asp:Label ID="lblename" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </td>
    </tr>
     <tr align="left">
            <td colspan="4" align="left">
               Employee ID :
                <asp:Label ID="lbleid" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
             </td>                        
    </tr>
```

I want to convert this code pdf here is my c# code

```
 Document Doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 72, 72, 82, 72);

   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
   PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, ms);

   Doc.Open();
   Doc.add(divprint) **//showing error**
   Doc.Close();
   Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
   Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Bhagavan.pdf");
   Response.End();
```

I want to convert this html code to PDf . Iam new to Itextsharp. Please give some hint.

Comment: @cracker I am using asp.net

Comment: The thing you posted as "HTML" is really "ASPX". iTextSharp doesn't know anything about ASPX or ASP.Net, _you_ need to get the HTML before passing it on. You'll want to look at calling `RenderControl` on your control. See this for a start: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6346602/231316