# How to check if Itemplate property has literal text before or after calling InstantiateIn()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET control, MyControl, with an Itemplate property:

> public Itemplate MyTemplate{ get; set; }

This allows me to put HTML between MyTemplate tags in markup, which will be instantiated like this in the rendering process:

```
if (MyTemplate!= null) {
    Control MyTemplateContainer = new Control();
    MyTemplate.InstantiateIn(MyTemplateContainer);
    Controls.Add(MyTemplateContainer);
}
```

Checking for `MyTemplate!=null` tells me whether or not MyTemplate tags are present in the control in markup, but not whether there is anything inside the tags.

The solution from this question, [Render Control Without Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346435/render-control-without-page), where we call RenderControl and then access StringWriter to turn the markup into a string, requires the page to be initialized first, which I would prefer not to do. Is there any other way to tell if MyTemplate tag has literal text in it?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (MyTemplate != null && MyTemplate.ChildControls != null && MyTemplate.ChildControls[0] != null && MyTemplate.ChildControls[0].GetType() == typeof (Literal))
{
  //Template has a control, and it's a literal
}
```

Comment: All inline text in an aspx template inside a server control get's turned into a Literal control by the aspx engine when it processes the page.